# PHP Nginx server - access files from home not web root

Tags: php, unix, nginx, webserver

I didn't really know how to word this question as my server knowledge is pretty poor. Basically I have a set up where when I SSH in I see this folder structure:

```
~/mysite.com
~/mysite.app
~/uploads
```

Both the .com and .app (test version) of my site run off the same database and code. The reason I do this is to commit changes to .app so the rest of my company can see next releases of the site and only when we're completely happy do we commit the same changes to the .com. However, due to the nature of how my site works there kept being lots of conflicts of uploads, as in someone would upload something to the .app domain and then if you logged into .com it would be trying to retrieve a file that didn't exist... I'm not sure I'm explaining that too well.

So what I've done is create an uploads folder in my home directory so now both the .com and .app domain upload files to this directory which would solve the problem. The problem is the scripts within the domain directories can't retrieve files from the upload directory (I'm having no problems putting the files there). How do I go about changing this? Is it a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Nginx, you can just add `location` inside the `server` block:

```
server {
    server_name mysite.com;

    root /var/www/mysite.com/;

    location /uploads/ {
        root /var/www;
        # or: "alias /var/www/uploads/;" if you want
    }

    # other locations
}
```

The same location is applied to `server {server_name mysite.app;}` block.